# PHP 5.4 - Call to undefined function http_head

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, php

i installed the pecl_http package.
My phpinfo says its enabled.

But i get this Error Message: `Fatal error: Call to undefined function http_head()`

Its Ubuntu 10.04.4

Comment: Did you enable the module in your php.ini and restart the service?

Comment: What's the version you have installed?

Comment: pecl/pecl_http is already installed and is the same as the released version 2.0.7

Answer (score 0):

`pecl_http` changed completely between versions 1 and 2 - code that was written for version 1.x will not work with 2.x. For the functions that I had used from version 1 there wasn't even an equivalent in version 2 so I had to code those from scratch.

Details of version 2 can be found at https://mdref.m6w6.name/http

It is unfortunate that version 2 wasn't put in PECL as `pecl_http2` as it's really a different library. To use any of the functions beginning `http_` you'll need to use version 1 of the library. Install the last 1.x version with:

```
pecl uninstall pecl_http
pecl install pecl_http-1.7.6
```